# "I'll teach you" VS. "I'll have you learn"

Tags: meaning

1. I'll teach you a lot more.
2. I'll have you learn a lot more.

What's the difference?

Comment: Not an English expert, just an opinion. "I will have you learn" sounds very forceful. As if the villain is in the middle of his speech towards the protagonist. "I will teach you a lot more", on the other hand, sounds quite friendly.

Comment: You are correct. “I’ll have you learn” can be quite aggressive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the logic here is similar to "I have painted my house" (I did it myself) and "I had my house painted" (I ordered someone to do it). In that case,

**"I'll teach you"** implies that I will personally be your teacher.

**"I'll have you learn"** implies that I will make you learn what is needed, but someone else may be your teacher (including yourself learning from your own mistakes).